# Android CountDownTimer not rendering properly

Tags: android, view, textview, countdowntimer

I have a simple Android countdown timer whose output is distorted.  I am trying to create a simple game where the user has to click a button repeatidly which in turn changes a drawable image from one to another through a course of 8 images.  The drawables render fine, but the countdown timer (which should could from 30 seconds downwards), seems to stick and/or generate incorrect numbers which do not represent the current amount of time passed.  Has anyone any advice on why this is happening or what I should investigate to mend this issue?

### MultitapGame.java

```
    public class MultitapGame extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multitapgame);

    final View btn = findViewById(R.id.gameButton);
    final View img = findViewById(R.id.game1);

    final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameCDT);
    final TextView mTextField2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameCDT2);
    final View mTextField3 = findViewById(R.id.gameCDT3);
    final View mTextField4 = findViewById(R.id.gameCDT4);


    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public int count = 0;


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setCount(getCount() + 1);
            new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                     int timeLeft =  (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) ;

                     ((TextView) mTextField).setText("seconds remaining: ");
                     final TextView mTextField2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameCDT2);
                        mTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(timeLeft + ""));

                 }

                 public void onFinish() {

                     int numTaps = count;
                     if(numTaps<150)
                     {
                         ((TextView) mTextField3).setText("Unlucky chucky! ");
                         ((TextView) mTextField4).setText("taps done: " + numTaps);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         ((TextView) mTextField3).setText("Congrats Bro :-) !");
                         ((TextView) mTextField4).setText("taps done: " + numTaps);
                     }
                 }
              }.start();


            if(count==15)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);}
            if(count==30)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);}
            if(count==45)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image4);}
            if(count==60)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==75)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}
            if(count==90)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==100)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}
            if(count==110)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==115)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}
            if(count==118)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==121)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}
            if(count==123)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==125)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}
            if(count==126)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image5);}
            if(count==127)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image6);}

            if(count==130)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image7);}
            if(count==140)
            {
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);}
            if(count==160)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.B00512756.angertwo",
                        "com.B00512756.angertwo.Strategies");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();}

        }


        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }


        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: Is the onTick() method run inside the UI Thread? If not, then you should use a handler or other method to update the UI from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with implementing CountDownTimer inside your onClick method.

I would suggest implementing it as a subclass that extends CountDownTimer, such as:

```
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

                 @Override
                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: ");
                     mTextField2.setText(String.valueOf((int) (millisUntilFinished/1000) + ""));

                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFinish() {

                     int numTaps = count;
                     if(numTaps<150)
                     {
                         mTextField3.setText("Unlucky chucky! ");
                         mTextField4.setText("taps done: " + numTaps);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         mTextField3.setText("Congrats Bro :-) !");
                         mTextField4.setText("taps done: " + numTaps);
                     }
                 }

    }
```

Also, it is a better idea to make the code inside onTick() as short as possible because the calls to `onTick(long)` are synchronized to this object. So one call to `onTick(long)` won't ever occur before the previous callback is complete. This is only relevant when the implementation of `onTick(long)` takes an amount of time to execute that is significant compared to the countdown interval. Thus, if it takes for your `onTick()` code to execute longer than a second, you will have lags in your countdown. That's why I made it shorter.

It is a better idea to initialize your TextViews inside your `onCreate()` and declare them as public class variables so that you will not have to do this everytime your counter ticks or finishes.

Next step is to initialize your timer in `onCreate`:

```
final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(30000,1000);
```

Finally, you need to start it in your `onClick()` method:

```
timer.start();
```